# Asynchronous reset mysteriously setting up output reg

Tags: asynchronous, verilog, reset

I have this code below:

```
module timer(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output reg signal // <--- PROBLEMATIC SIGNAL
);

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
    if(reset)
        signal <= 1;
    else
        signal <= 0;
    end
endmodule
```

and this testbench, which was executed on modelsim:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`define PERIOD 20

module timer_tb;
    logic clk;
    logic reset;
    logic signal;

    timer inst(
        .clk(clk),
        .reset(reset),
        .signal(signal)
    );

    initial
    begin
        clk = 0;
        forever clk = #(`PERIOD/2) ~clk;
    end

    initial
    begin
        reset = 0; //<--- RESET STARTS CLEANED. 
        #(`PERIOD)
        reset = 1;
        #(`PERIOD)
        reset = 0;
        #(`PERIOD*3)
        reset = 1;
        #(`PERIOD)
        reset = 0;

        #(`PERIOD*3)
        $display("End of the simulation");
        $stop;
    end
endmodule
```

Output reg `signal` starts HIGH but in the code, this reg depends of `reset`, and the `reset` starts DOWN. I don't understand why `signal` register is HIGH in the beginning of the simulation as the `reset` starts surely DOWN.

I need the `signal` starting DOWN and only be set up IF `reset` go to 1 (condition posedge `reset` just like my code).

Please take a look on [this print of the waveform](http://postimg.org/image/5wktylub9/) for clear understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your waveform has clock-to-q delay, but your RTL model doesn't have any delay. This implies you are not running RTL simulation. Rather your are running a synthesized gate level simulation or getting output from an FPGA.

Something to consider is that in the test bench, `clk` and `reset` start as X not 0. The become 0 at time zero. Verilog allows indeterminate order for parallel process, it is optional to execute an always block at time zero regardless of its sensitivity list, and an X in for a comparison evaluates as true. Depending how the vendor implemented the simulator, it is possible the always block got executed first. `reset` being X evaluates as true and assigns `signal` to 1. Then `clk` and `reset` are assigned to 0. All of this happens at time 0 and cannot be seen in waveform.

This allowed unpredictability is an unintentional slice of reality. When you first power up a circuit what you initially get may be unpredictable (this is from process variation, physical routing, glitches while the power supply is being ramped, etc. ). You use a reset to get the design into a known state.

If you want to prevent the `clk` and `reset` from ever begin X, then change the data-type in the test-bench from `logic` to `bit` (note:`bit` and `logic` are SystemVerilog). Another option that should work (not 100% guaranteed) is to initialize `clk` and `reset` in the same line as it's declaration.

```
logic clk = 1'b0;
logic reset = 1'b0;
```

This should work assuming you are running simulation. If you are running on FPGA you cannot guaranty this time zero behavior through changes in your test bench.

The cleanest solution is to start with `reset` enabled. You should not care what the values are before reset at time zero.

Comment: Thank you by your explanation. You are right, I'm running a gate level simulation at modelsim-altera software.
I tried to apply your suggestions (changes from logic to bit at testbench, and  initialize clk and reset as 0 in the same line as it's declaration.), but I'm still getting the same result. It is incredible.
[Signal](http://postimg.org/image/i2rg1rkhn/) is still toggling to 1 and getting back when clk stands up, even everyone starting as 0 (not X).
This is very curious.

Answer (score 0):

`signal` has not initial value, so its value at time 0 is undefined. Some simulators initialize it to 0, others to 1, others to X.

Use an initial block to have `signal` initialized to 0.

```
module timer(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output wire signal
);

    reg rsignal;
    assign signal = rsignal;

    initial begin
      rsignal = 1'b0;
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
    if(reset)
        rsignal <= 1;
    else
        rsignal <= 0;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I can't use initial statements because I need to construct a synthesizable design.
Another point is that I tested the design without the "or posedge reset" sensibility and I get "signal" starting correctly with 0.
I don't know why this is happening as consequence of insertion of the asynchronous reset...

Comment: `initial` is synthesizable, at least for FPGA's and CPLD's. Probably not for ASIC's.

Comment: I used the initial statement and your code. But the signal keeps starting HIGH. Take a look on these prints:
[waveform](http://postimg.org/image/m1ig5ii0n/)
||
[your design at quartus](http://postimg.org/image/3ry7w65b1/)

Comment: Maybe it's your test bench. Look at this interactive Verilog editor with your design and a Verilog-only test-bench (no `logic` datatype): http://www.edaplayground.com/x/GCC

Answer (score 0):

The default value of reg is 'x' or undefined and default value of wire is 'Hi-Z' , so in this case your output (signal) is reg type so simulator took default value accordingly, to get a default value of '0' SystemVerilog(IEEE1800-2012) comes with bit data type, you can try using bit in the output as shown below

```
 module timer(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output bit signal 
);

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
    if(reset)
        signal <= 1;
    else
        signal <= 0;
    end
endmodule
```

EDIT: I am not sure of quartus but conversely you can try initializing the value to 0 or 1 at the output by this method, It should work in Verilog

```
module timer(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output reg signal=0
);

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
    if(reset)
        signal <= 1;
    else
        signal <= 0;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am limited to develop a verilog design. I can't use system verilog assignments or constructs.
Therefore, in quartus software I get this error after try using "bit" construct:
"Error (10161): Verilog HDL error at timer.v(5): object "bit" is not declared"